# A key cannot be configured on 'ApplicationUser' because it is a derived type. The key must be configured on the root type 'IdentityUser'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add an extra property to IdentityUser table. When I want to run the migration this error appears:
A key cannot be configured on 'ApplicationUser' because it is a derived type. The key must be configured on the root type 'IdentityUser'. If you did not intend for 'IdentityUser' to be included in the model, ensure that it is not referenced by a DbSet property on your context, referenced in a configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation on a type that is included in the model.
I searched a lot and I tried them but none of them worked for me.

This is the application user class:

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

This is my context:

```
public class OnlineExamContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public OnlineExamContext(DbContextOptions<OnlineExamContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    #region Questions
    public DbSet<UserAnswer> userAnswers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Question> questions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChoiceQuestionSelection> choiceQuestionSelections { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QuestionCategory> questionCategories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TrueFalseQuestion> trueFalseQuestions { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region users
    public DbSet<UserCourse> userCourses { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region other entities
    public DbSet<Course> courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StudentGrade> studentGrades { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Exam> exams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SiteSetting> siteSettings { get; set; }
    #endregion

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var cascadeFKs = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetForeignKeys())
            .Where(fk => !fk.IsOwnership && fk.DeleteBehavior == DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        foreach (var fk in cascadeFKs)
            fk.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
                  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
    }

}
```

This is the startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;             
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-";

            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
            
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I should have changed all IdentityUsers to ApplicationUser even the navigations to my models.Like this:

```
   public class Question
    {
       [Key]
       public int QuestionId { get; set; }//1
       [ForeignKey("UserId")]
       public virtual ApplicationUser IdentityUser { get; set; }
     }
```